# SpriteKit - SKActions or updating positions in update function

Tags: swift, html, sprite-kit, skaction

I am quite new to SpriteKit, coming from about 4 months playing around with HTML5. Using [Mark Wihlberg's](https://github.com/maxwihlborg) HTML5 youtube game tutorials, my programs always constantly updated a player or object's position.

Example if it helps:

```
function run() {
    var loop = function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);

        update(); //here I would add maybe 3 to a player's x pos and redraw in draw()
        draw();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}
```

But looking at various SpriteKit tutorials online, many use `SKAction` to move nodes across the screen.

My question is whether constantly updating a node's position in SpriteKit is unorthodox, or frowned upon, and I should get used to using actions, and why?

Comment: You could either use SKActions outside the update function, or increment/decrement the position or rotation in update function, it's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't frowned upon, and it's good to know how to do these things manually. If it's fairly straightforward, regular movement, then `SKAction` is fine. For more complicated stuff (and SKActions can actually get complicated, with sprites following paths and bezier curves etc), use the `Update()` function, iterate over your sprites (using `enumerateChildNodesWithName` or similar) and move them as necessary.

You can combine the 2 - move the sprites in `Update()` and animate them with an SKAction, or vice-versa.

Bear in mind that you don't call `Update()`; it is called automatically by the game engine 60 times a second. It gets passed a time, so you can work out exactly how long it has been since Update() was last called (not always 1/60s)